# Setting proration_behavior to none in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to update my subscription in such a way to remove the prorartion behaviour. Here's what  I did, (It didn't work and while printing the $subscription_object  I didn't see any proration_behavior field despite what it is written in the API documentation of a subscription object)

```
 $subscription_obj = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($checkout_session->subscription); 
\Stripe\Subscription::update($subscription_obj->id, [
        'proration_behavior' => 'none',
      ]);
```

I also tried :

```
$subscription_obj->proration_behavior = 'none';
$subscription_obj->save();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only relevant when you are [making another change to the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations), such as upgrading/downgrading the plan, changing the billing cycle anchor or canceling. If you're otherwise not changing the subscription, there is nothing to prorate and this will have no effect.

If you are trying to disable prorations for some other change, you should provide `proration_behavior=none` with that update request.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, this is what I am trying to do : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621644/stripe-disable-proration
My goal is to cancel subscriptions on a specific date or after a certain number of months .
so according to your answer I should do this ?

Comment: `$stripe->subscriptions->update(`
        `'sub_xxxxx',`
       `['cancel_at' =>'xxxxx', proration_behavior=none ]`
       ` );`

Please tell me if the syntax if i'm wrong or if i should put prorate = false instead of this.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work:
`$final = strtotime("+2 month", $subscription_obj->start_date); \Stripe\Subscription::update($subscription_obj->id, ['cancel_at' => $final,'proration_behavior' => 'none',]); $subscription_obj->save(); `

Comment: "If you are trying to disable prorations for some other change" .. yes my change is that I want to change the `cancel_at` field.

Comment: If the cancelation will be in a future billing period (ie, a date after the next renewal), `cancel_at` will always lead to a proration and cannot be disabled with the parameter you ask about. This is documented in the API reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at

Comment: Thank you so much. I will keep the proration as i have no other choice.